# WPF Date Picker with 3 Boxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement to have a datepicker with 3 separate boxes for month, day, and year (see image below).

[image]

The default one was not deemed acceptable by the client. However I'm really struggling to see how this can be done in WPF. I thought perhaps maybe it could be just a styling change but I'm not really finding any examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can your own control binding the properties of your required text boxes to added properties of your control that wrap the data structure of the date time.

There are a few ways to skin the cat. Since you are here asking you might struggle with fully making your own control (using dependency properties for "Year" etc.) so I would suggest going the simple approach and building a User Control that has a DateTime expected as the data context.

This would allow you to have textboxes that are bound to the year value.
    [TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Year}"/>

Repeat this for the other values that you wish to bind directly to.

Then in your parent control just pull in the created user control and bind to your property that holds the datetime value.

```
<local:CustomDateTimePicker DataContext="{Binding Path=DateTimeProperty}" />
```

Comment: Serious formatting issues. Could use help why the "<TextBox Text="{Bidning Path=Text}" />" refuses to render.